# ShowModal not triggering the conditional statement for the dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dialog, wxwidgets, showmodaldialog

I am calling a dialog from a tree control menu as below. The `OnSavePattern` function follows after that.

```
    if(itemId==A1)
    {
        A2Dlg A3(this, wxID_ANY);
        if(A3.ShowModal()==wxID_OK)
        {
           A3.OnSavePattern();
           wxGetApp().getPattern()->var1=1;
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////

    void A2Dlg::OnSavePattern()
    {
        if(radioButtonYM->GetValue())
            wxGetApp().getPattern()->var2=1;
        else if(radioButtonY->GetValue())
            wxGetApp().getPattern()->var2=2;
        else if(radioButtonM->GetValue())
            wxGetApp().getPattern()->var2=3;
        Refresh();
    }
```

However, sometimes, the code does not call `OnSavePattern` on hitting Ok. I am not sure why this happens, and also I am not creating another instance of A2Dlg. Any help would be great. Please let me know if more explanation of the problem is needed.

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly? Are you saying that the code does `not` call OnSavePattern() when you press `OK`? Or something else? Please describe you problem.

Comment: Yes @Igor. It sometimes does not call OnSavePattern on hitting Ok. I modified the problem statement

Comment: is it possible that the `itemId` is not `A1`? Do you have a code branch for this case? What is the pattern of the code not calling the function? What do you do differently?

Comment: itemId is A1. Do you mean if the code branches out to any other function by code branch? I didn't understand what you mean by code branch. It should not as it is just a conditional statement that is true when Ok is hit. Sometimes the code works properly, but sometimes it doesn't. That is the most confusing part to me

Comment: what I meant is "if there is an `else` statement to that if? Also, is there any pattern on when the code does not work properly?

Comment: @Igor no else statement. It doesn't follow a specific pattern. Sometimes it doesn't work on the third call to the dialog, sometimes on the second call. So as a work-around, I took out the dialog option and instead made 3 tree sub-items under `itemId A1` and tried it with a message box (wxYES and wxNO) for each sub-item and that seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: do you have any data validation routine in the dialog? Can you re-produce this with the simplest possile changes to the treectrl sample? Also, what version of wx do you have? What OS/toolkit?

Comment: It is not clear what `this` refers to.